# Can't creat a recovery disk on windows 10: Some required files are missin

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, recovery-disk

Recently I bought a asus vivobook notebook which has **genuine win 10 home** pre-installed. But I have installed **ubuntu 16.04** alongside it. For doing so I had to shrink the partition in which windows is installed. I have done it with windows' built in disk manager. Now I want to make a recovery disk so that I can recover my genuine windows in future. 
So I go to 
    `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Recovery`
And clicked `Creat a recovery drive`
Then **`Next`** on the new window. But after that it says

> We can't create a recovery drive on this PC
>   Some required files are missing.

But as shown in **Fig1** windows has a recovery partition in disk1(*last partition*). Is it the shrinking that caused this damage? If so what are the alternatives to recover my genuine windows now? Or how can I help myself with that recovery partition on my hard-drive and what is it for? Or is it anything else that causing this problem?

[Fig1.Windows partition=OS(C:),second partition on disk1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRumg.png)
[2.Creating recovery disk fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmkEK.png)

Comment: The recovery partition is just for that, to restore the factory installed OS.....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pc3OamFf9-I

Comment: There is no 'reset your pc' option in my case @Moab

Answer (score 1):

Start by running
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
to check the integrity of Windows.
It will tell you if any Windows files are missing.

If the SFC scan finished correctly, try this method coming from the post
[Can't create a Windows 10 recovery drive. Some required files are missing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/cant-create-a-windows-10-recovery-drive-some/6dd29184-2ddd-48f2-803a-a788cf9345b0?auth=1&page=1)
by a user called Criostoir O'Dochartaigh:

> Open command prompt in elevated mode and type:
>
> ```
> reagentc /disable
> ```
>
> then type:
>
> ```
> reagentc /setreimage /path \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE
> ```
>
> Then type:
>
> ```
> reagentc /enable
> ```
>
> You may need to change "harddisk0" to "harddiskX" where X is the
>   number of your "C" drive and "partition1" to partitionX where X is the
>   partition number to conform with your system setup. To check go to
>   Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Computer
>   Management/Storage/Diskmanagment.  The disk partitions are numbered
>   from the left of the screen starting with number 1.